# What's an adverb meaning "focused on one thing/goal"?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Sample sentence:** (may not be factually true) "The American Federation of Labor ___ campaigned for higher wages throughout its existence."

Words like **"intently"** don't embody what I'm looking for; they don't connote industry towards a singular goal; and they have the extra meaning of eagerness and attention (human qualities), while the word I am looking for should be used with like a nonhuman actor like a business.

**"Singularly"** does not work because it means something else entirely, but if it didn't it sounds like it would work.

**"Specifically"** and **"precisely"** don't work because time-wise they seem perfective, like a single point in time, while the adverb I'm looking for should describe a process or otherwise something happening over a long period of time. And ["—used to indicate the exact identity, purpose, or use of something"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specifically) says "purpose", like a passive quality, while I want a "goal", something that is able to be achieved (and so there should exist someone achieving it).

**"Resolutely"** does not work because it has that extra "determined" and "unwavering" flavor, and it seems like it is a human quality. And having a single goal does not mean you are ["marked by firm determination"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolute)

**"Dedicatedly"** doesn't work because it doesn't seem like a real word ([less than 0.00001% on ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dedicatedly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdedicatedly%3B%2Cc0)) and **"devotedly"** means  ["in an extremely loving and loyal way"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/devotedly). Similarly "staunchly".

I want something that means **"concentratedly"** like "focus one's attention or mental effort on a particular object or activity." (from Google) or **"targetedly"** like "select as an object of attention" (also from Google). Related phrases: ["focus on", "devote oneself to"](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/focus%20on)

It should also contain **"solely"** or **"uniquely"**.

Comment: single-minded(ly)

Comment: If you're talking about real optical _focus_, probly the word you want would be _accurately_. But it seems likely you're talking about a metaphoric _focus_ here, so you should consult your metaphor.

Comment: "Repeatedly" would also fit nicely

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Single-mindedly*** fits the bill quite nicely, I think...

Single-minded:

> having one driving purpose or resolve : DETERMINED, DEDICATED
> <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single-minded)*</sub>

> having or showing a single aim or purpose:
> *a single-minded program.*
> <sub>*from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/single-minded?s=t)*</sub>

Plus, of course, the suffix *-ly*, "a suffix forming adverbs from adjectives: gladly; gradually; secondly." *(also from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ly?s=t))*

Or, as Cambridge has it directly:

> in a way that is very determined and thinks only about achieving a particular thing
> <sub>*from [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/single-mindedly)*</sub>

(I would argue that their definition would be improved by saying "... achieving one particular thing".)

Comment: "single-mindedly" does sound a bit human but the definition works for me

Answer (score 2):

"The American Federation of Labor **relentlessly** campaigned for  higher wages throughout its existence."

> Meaning of relentless in English   ... US  /rɪˈlent·ləs/   continuing
> in a determined way without any interruption:
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/relentless

Answer (score 0):

To me, "solely" embodies all of the required meanings. Personally I think "single-mindedly" sounds a little negative, as if they should have been doing more things at the same time.

Comment: But solely would also mean they were only doing one thing.  In fact I think it implies it more than "single-mindedly" does.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like *unflaggingly* for this.

> The American Federation of Labor *unflaggingly* campaigned for higher wages throughout its existence.

> *unflagging*: not declining in strength or vigor; tireless ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unflagging)); unrelenting ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unflaggingly)); persistent or untiring. ([Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unflagging))

Nothing against *single-minded* (the definition certainly fits); it's just that for me, that word has always had a bit of a negative connotation –as if you're incapable of seeing the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Only** as in this is literally the one thing they did.

> The American Federation of Labor **only** campaigned for higher wages throughout its existence.

as a single fact or instance and nothing more or different

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only

Answer (score 0):

If you say

> The American Federation of Labor ***persistently*** campaigned for higher wages throughout its existence.

the reader will understand that the federation persists in that particular goal, not in general.

Among the synonyms of [***persistent***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/persistently.html) you will also find *single-mindedly* which, I agree, fits your purpose very nicely. ***Persistently***, however, does have some tenacity and obstinacy about it that helps to enhance perhaps a little more the connotation of *concentration*.

Answer (score 0):

What about chiefly, predominantly, or centrally?

There's also principally and cardinally, but I'm not sure if those imply a degree of "moral correctness".